# java file compilation with file extension

Tags: java, javac

When we compile java program we use `javac file.java` command but while running we use `java file`.

So why it is necessary to explicitly specify file extension while compiling and not needed when we run the java program?

Comment: No, when running we use `java <classname>`. Not the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when you "run" the java .class compiled file you are telling the Java application launcher which class contains the main method. The launcher starts the Java runtime environment and loads the specified class.

If you write `java MyClass`, then the class with the main method is `MyClass`. Note that it would be erroneous to write `java MyClass.class`, since `MyClass.class` is not the name of the class.

When you compile with `javac MyClass.java` you need to tell the java compiler the extension, because it is a file and it need to find it.

Comment: Thank you. I got my doubt clear now. Since a single java file can contain as many number of classes but only one `main()` class. So while running we only need to specify the class name containing `main()`.

Comment: @SanTech - Actually, your reasoning is incorrect.  1) You can't run a ".java" file because it isn't compiled.  (The fact that it *could* contain multiple classes is moot.)  2) A ".class" file will only ever contain one compiled class.   Hence, it would make sense to run `java MyClass.class` ... except that it doesn't work that way.  3) The real reason is simple.  You do it that way **because** that is the way that the `java` command works.  Period.

Comment: OK. To make it even simpler, `javac` command takes file for compilation and `java` command takes class name for running.

Comment: Also, the class file could be anywhere on classpath, or even in a JAR file if such is provided. You do not specify the class file; you specify the fully qualified class name, and let the class loader figure out where it is.

Answer (score 8):

> So why it is necessary to explicitly specify file extension while compiling and not needed when we run the java program?

Because that is the way that the tools are implemented:

- The `javac` command expects file pathnames
- The `java` command expects Java class names<sup>1</sup>.

They were implemented like this 20 something years ago, and the need for backwards compatibility has outweighed the need for change<sup>2</sup>.

It wasn't necessary to design the tools that way.  (They could have done it differently.)  But the discussions of *why* they designed it that way are:

- discussions (off topic)
- opinion based (off topic), and
- moot.

---

<sup>1 - This is an over-simplification.  You can use the `-jar` option and provide an *executable* JAR file instead of a class name.  Also, from Java 9 onward, the `java` command can compile and run a single Java source file in one operation.

2 - One could make a case that it would be better for beginners if the tools worked differently.  However, it is really not that hard to understand the tools if the newbie pays attention .... and bothers to read the documentation and/or a decent tutorial and/or listens in class.</sup>